# Multiplying files from different folders based on similar date in filename using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000732, iteration

I am fairly new to Python and ArcPy.

I've been trying to get files originating from different directories and multiplying files from directory a only if directory b had files containing exact same dates within the filename.
Example of file a: 20020101_105433.img 
Example of file b: 20020101.img

So I wrote this code thinking it might be able to recognise that 20020101_105433.img can be used to multiply against another file from the other directory that contains the same date within i.e. 20020101.img

```
import arcpy
import string
from  math import *
from arcpy import *
from arcpy.sa import *
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import join

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

BP = "H:\\NorthSea\\Images4AllDates\\BPnoEo\\"
Eo = "C:\\Users\\robyn\\Desktop\\NCEPre2\\Watts2Eo\\"
output = "C:\\Users\\robyn\\Desktop\\FinalPPresults\\"
arcpy.env.cellSize = "MINOF"

netSW = os.listdir(Eo)
chlKd = os.listdir(BP)

for files in netSW and chlKd:
    SW = os.path.join(Eo, files)
    filenameSW = SW[40:48]
    CC = os.path.join(BP, files)
    filenameCC = CC[35:43]
    if files.endswith(".img"):
        if (files in SW[40:48]) == (files in CC[35:43]):
        #or if filenameSW == filenameCC:
            Output = output + files
            BPI = Raster(SW) * Raster(CC)
            BPI.save(Output)
            print Output + " done"
```

The error number is 000732 (Dataset does not exist).

I've had a look at the re.compile module but also don't really understand it enough, essentially it should have this pattern: re.compile("[0-9]{8}") where there can be numbers from 0-9 and 8 characters in a sequence to match the pattern?

I have possibly got this wrong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looping over multiple directories, you can't do it with an `and` like you do here:

```
for files in (netSW and chlKd):
```

(parenthesis added for clarity, it means the same as in your code).

What this does is assign `netSW` to `files`, but `chlKd` is never used.  You can see that by placing a `print files` in that loop, it will show just files from one of the two folders. Here is [another explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4477856/1781026) on Stack Overflow about using `and`.

You are splitting your file names with indexes, e.g. here `SW[40:48]`. This can result in wrong/broken file names when paths change, it is indeed better to use the `os.path` module or regular expressions. I added those to the code below.

I might have mixed up the file names and I don't have arcpy to test right now, but I hope you get the idea of what I tried to fix.

```
import arcpy
import string
from  math import *
from arcpy import *
from arcpy.sa import *
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import join
import re

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.cellSize = "MINOF"

BP = "H:\\NorthSea\\Images4AllDates\\BPnoEo\\"
Eo = "C:\\Users\\robyn\\Desktop\\NCEPre2\\Watts2Eo\\"
output = "C:\\Users\\robyn\\Desktop\\FinalPPresults\\"

netSW = os.listdir(Eo)
chlKd = os.listdir(BP)

netSW_regex = re.compile("([0-9]{8}).img") # matches 20020101_105433.img
chlKd_regex = re.compile("([0-9]{8})_([0-9]{6}).img") # matches 20020102.img

for fileSW in netSW:
    for fileCC in chlKd:
        SW = os.path.join(Eo, fileSW)
        CC = os.path.join(BP, fileCC)

        netSW_matcher = netSW_regex.match(fileSW)
        chlKd_matcher = chlKd_regex.match(fileCC)
        if netSW_matcher and chlKd_matcher and netSW_matcher.group(1) == chlKd_matcher.group(1):
            print "Multiplying {} and {}".format(fileSW, fileCC)
            target_path = os.path.join(result, fileSW)
            BPI = Raster(SW) * Raster(CC)
            BPI.save(target_path)
            print "Done {}".format(target_path)
```

Comment: Thanks chrki! Don't know why I can't upvote your answer but you have extra points for also helping with recognising filename based on regular expression, thank you!